# Alternatives to AngularJS for Spring MVC 4 RESTFul Web Services

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I am currently elaborating on the design of a Spring MVC 4 CRUD application providing RESTful Web Services.

I am leaning towards the use of AngularJS on the front-end but wonder what could be the alternatives for AngularJS, the main criteria for me being 
a) simplicity 
b) robustness 
c) long term support of the chosen technology.

The application targets a limited number of government users: lots of forms, basic look&feel from year 2000. It's not expected to be super stylish, fancy and responsive but should be just functional and use technology that would last over time.

Comment: http://whichcatisyourjavascriptframework.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Grails? (https://grails.org/)
Grails uses SpringBoot under the covers and the Convention over Configuration paradigm. In addition, the Spring MVC pattern is built in, along with Spring DI, Groovy, and GORM (A Groovy DSL over Hibernate). It's a nice web framework.

If you want rapid development, especially with a relatively simple UI, this may be a great choice for you.